# pass parameter not working in this situation

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following and it seems to work fine:

In my .cs file :

```
 protected void menu_ItemClick(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.RadMenuEventArgs e)
 {
    string value = (e.Item.Value).ToString();
    WtrClientDS.SelectCommand = "SELECT * from Prog where  ProgId = " + value;
 }
```

In the .aspx file:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="WtrClientDS" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProgSQL %>">

</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

As mentioned, what I have above works fine but I do not think it is best practice.

What Like to do instead is something where I have the select command inside of the .aspx file like the following but not working:

Inside of the .cs file

```
     protected void menu_ItemClick(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.RadMenuEventArgs e)
     {

          string value = (e.Item.Value).ToString();
          // changed below per input from user but still does not work. 
          WtrClientDS.SelectParameters.Add(new Parameter("LocId", System.TypeCode.String, value)); 
     }
```

Inside of the .aspx file:

```
      <asp:SqlDataSource ID="WtrClientDS" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProgSQL %>" 
      SelectCommand =  "SELECT * from Prog where  ProgId = @LocId">

    <SelectParameters> 
       <asp:Parameter Name="LocId" Type="String"  /> 
    </SelectParameters>
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

What I have above simply does not work. Doesn't give an error but simply does not work. 
I also wanted to know which is the more preferred method/ideal way of doing it.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a new `SQLDataSource`:

```
protected void menu_ItemClick(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.RadMenuEventArgs e)
 {
      string value = (e.Item.Value).ToString();
      string strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStrings:ProgSQL"].ConnectionString; 

      SqlDataSource WtrClientDS = new SqlDataSource(); 
      WtrClientDS.ConnectionString = strConn;
      WtrClientDS.SelectCommand = "SELECT * from Prog where ProgId = @LocId"
      WtrClientDS.SelectParameters.Add(new Parameter("LocId", System.TypeCode.String, value));

      //refresh your control
      WtrClients.DataSource = WtrClientDS.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
      WtrClients.Rebind();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. I am getting Error 2 The type or namespace name 'Parameter' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Add `using System.Web.UI.WebControls;` in your usings.

Comment: Thanks Francis. I did that but it is still not working. Is there anything I am missing in the .aspx file that you can see?

Comment: Yes, I changed it to WtrClientDS.SelectParameters.Add(new Parameter("LocId", System.TypeCode.String, value)); , you had it as Int32 but as it is a string, I just changed to string

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18426/discussion-between-web-dev-and-francis-p)